# Seeding images with active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I recently implemented Active Storage into my rails 5.2 project and I'm encountering a problem when seeding users with an avatar:

```
user = User.new(
  email: "user@email.com",
  password: 123456,
  name: "User Userson"
)
user.skip_confirmation!
user.save!
user.avatar.attach(io: File.open('app/assets/images/avatar.png'), filename: 'avatar.png', content_type: 'image/png')
```

This code doesn't stop or move on to the next seeding.

It seems that the `attach()` starts to upload the image asynchronous and when it gets around to upload it halts the whole function.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

`User.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 devise :database_authenticatable, :async, :registerable, :confirmable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :invitable

 has_many :posts
 has_many :bulletins
 has_many :bulletin_comments
 has_one :organization, foreign_key: 'landlord_id'
 belongs_to :apartment, optional: true
 has_one_attached :avatar

 validates_presence_of :name
end
```

Comment: Did you try it from rails console ? I did the same from both console and seed works perfect. Put some `puts` in your seed file and then try to debug.

Comment: Yes - works from console and it works. I am creating multiple users and have have adding puts and result is the first user is created but halts at number 2

Comment: I also tried with first 20 then 50 users. No halt anywhere. Maybe you are missing something in your model or due to validation. Can you post your `user.rb` model ?

Comment: At time of deletion you might have some halt but that only from console , from code there is no halt in activestorage.

Comment: @ts Added user.rb

Comment: I have tried all your code all is working. Can you share how are you going to save multiple users ?

Comment: Can you please put only this code in your `seed.rb` and then check by rake db:seed

`for i in 1..50
  puts "user  - #{i}"
  user = User.new
  user.email = "user#{i}@gmail.com"
  user.password = '123456'
  user.skip_confirmation!
  user.save!
  user.avatar.attach(io: File.open('app/assets/images/avatar.png'), filename: 'avatar.png', content_type: 'image/png')
end`

Comment: It works - I am running multiple seeding scripts, and broke when I implemented active storage, so I assumed that was the problem. Trying to figure out what seems to be the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179815/discussion-between-t-s-and-frankfromdenmark).

Comment: Please try with this it will work 

`rails db:migrate && rails db:seed `
put && between migrate and db:seed
It seems db:seed caches the column info somehow